# Определение  координат пользователя

Tags: android

Подскажите все известные способы определения координат местоположения пользователя. Мне известно только GPS.
От чего зависит погрешность определения координат и в каких пределах?
И если приложение определяем мои координаты, то какое средство связи использует для этого?

Comment: я не android разработчик и наверняка сутра вам подскажут что-то более подробно по android, а я пока могу сказать что для определения координат по gps используется 3+1 спутника и такое местоположение очень точное, его погрешность вряд ли может быть больше метра. Если работа с gps приемником не доступна, то местоположение определяется с помощью вышек сотовой связи (устройство работает с ближней) и погрешность может достигать десятков метров.  

достоверность информации не гарантирую, пытаюсь помочь чем могу... может, и мне кто поможет :)

Comment: кроме указанного выше, еще координаты определяются по доступным WiFi сетям. При этом даже не обязательно к ним подключаться. Суть та же, что и с базовыми станциями - обычная триангуляция.

Также можно определять по данным от оператора, но для этого нужно с оператором связи договориться.

Ещё видел способ - с помощью блютуса. Он сканирует доступные блютусы рядом, а для некоторых можно получить их координаты.